# umlauts will not be saved in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i will save umlauts in a mysql db so i have an textarea which will be saved with a form. if i dont use any umlauts it will save proper but if i use one of the umlauts it stops to save at the point where the umlaut starts and also cut off the rest of the text..

so i know about the utf-8 and i have in my mysql connection an

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

but what can i do to save this correctly ?

i use mysql_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars to save but is there something to transform or any kind ?

Comment: what is the collation of the column / database? 
[`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) shows information about a table, including the collation.

Comment: Are you sure it's not saving correctly? I once thought the same thing, but it turned out to be PhpMyAdmin not displaying the database contents correctly.

Comment: SHOW TABLE STATUS show me some information but nothing about collation ? or which information is needed ?

Comment: ok charset wasnt set right..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is able to store those characters so you don't need htmlspecialchars to store it in my MySQL database. Once you retrieve it and want to print it, you might want to use htmlspecialchars, but it's not always neccesary. What behavior do you get once you remove htmlspecialchars?

Comment: i also tried without htmlspecialchars but same result

Comment: Have you tried to "manually" insert it into the MySQL database? As in, not using variable input but simply executing a query such as `INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES ('Testing ümlaut')`?

Comment: A quick thought, are you sure you have your MySQL table set up properly so it takes these characters? I vaguely remember a problem where as if you set the collation wrong it won't work either, not sure though. Check if both your Character set and Collation are set to utf8